# How to ccDrawPoly and fill?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, opengl-es-2.0

```
- (void)draw {
lines[0] = ccp(self.l.x + (segmentIndex[0] * segmentSpacing), self.l.y);
lines[1] = ccp(self.l.x + (segmentIndex[1] * segmentSpacing), self.l.y + segmentHeight * 1);
lines[2] = ccp(self.l.x + (segmentIndex[2] * segmentSpacing), self.l.y + segmentHeight * 2);
lines[3] = ccp(self.l.x + (segmentIndex[3] * segmentSpacing), self.l.y + segmentHeight * 3);
lines[4] = ccp(lines[3].x + segmentWidth, lines[3].y);
lines[5] = ccp(lines[2].x + segmentWidth, lines[2].y);
lines[6] = ccp(lines[1].x + segmentWidth, lines[1].y);
lines[7] = ccp(lines[0].x + segmentWidth, lines[0].y);

ccDrawPoly(lines, 8, YES);
//ccDrawSolidPoly(lines, 8, [self color]);
```

}

The ccDrawPoly line draws the zig-zag style shape I intend to draw. 
There are 4 Y segments and each one has a point determined by segmentIndex & segmentSpacing, then +segmentWidth on the x for a total of 8 points.
I go down the left-most points first, then walk my way back up.

When I call ccDrawSolidPoly, it fills in the shape in a different way. It fills in a polygon using all the outermost points instead of drawing lines in the order I set in points.

How do I do ccDrawPoly and fill?

Answer (score -1):

Write my own function, apparently.

Forum results showed people editing the cocos2d ccDrawSolidPoly function.